# how to give scroll control with gui in python

Tags: python, user-interface, uiscrollview

i am opening a file in a gui label. 
the file i have is big, i need a scroll for it in gui frame.
the code i am using for loading the file and displaying it in a frame is

```
from Tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Vulnerability Report")
f = open("hola.txt", "r").read()
Label(tk, text=f) .grid(row=0)

tk.mainloop()
```

Here is the screenshot: [I want a scroll here through which i can read the whole file up and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQfap.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you are using Canvas instead of Frame and why you are loading a large file on a Label, but you cannot attach a Scrollbar to a label.  Tkinter has a ScrolledText widget.  Do `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText` and use it as one would a Text widget.

Comment: Better, now replace Label with ScrolledText.